# how to smartly rewrite a python script that used to use XSLT?

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, xslt

I have an old python app that used to use XSLT to transform some XML data (two types of xml files with their respective xslt ones) to produce html output.

I'd like to port this app to appengine, but, sadly, appengine's python version doesn't support xslt.

Is there an easy way to rewrite my code without manually parsing and checking for given tags in the xml inputs?

in other words, do you have any idea of a generic way to do this?

Thanks and sorry for my poor english!

Comment: Your English is great, don't undersell yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @Rafe, it's actually the 4th language I've learnt. So, I'm doing my best :)

Comment: Do you need to do it at server side? Otherwise you can use javascript on the client side to do that.

Comment: Another "idea", I don't know if it's feasable for GAE, but you could just reference the XSLT transform on your XML and let the browser do the work for you at client side.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no working XSLT implementation in pure python. You may be able to adapt your python code to run on jython, which would give you access to java's XSLT implementation. This is described in this [blog post](http://jython.xhaus.com/transforming-with-xslt-on-google-appengine-and-jython/).

You will have to decide if porting/testing your existing code to jython is a better option than writing your own case specific xml parser/transformer.

Comment: Thanks anthony, I've actually been on that very blog post, but honnestly it looks much of struggle to set up jyton (which I've never used btw) on GAE. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It's not a struggle at all. All you have to do is download a zip file, extract it into a directory structure, move a few files around, use a single "jar" command to create a WAR file, then upload to AppEngine. The instructions are here [Jython on Google AppEngine](http://opensource.xhaus.com/projects/1/wiki/ModjyGoogleAppEngine)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt) to do XSLT tranformations, AND lxml should work with older python versions (web site says it supports 2.3 through 3.2).

Comment: `lxml` is a wrapper around C libraries, not pure Python; as such it can't be used on AppEngine.

Answer (score 0):

If your XSLTs aren't **too** hideous, it might not be terribly hard to port them to Python using ElementTree's iterparse function (http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm, and see http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2006/11/06/iterparse_filter.html).

You'd have to rewrite your XSLT templates as Python functions that could be called during parsing as element "events" are encountered, and you might have to store some document state to allow certain kinds of xsl:template/@match patterns to be handled, but it probably wouldn't be too nasty.